# Oracle 10g Express .NET Connector

Tags: c#, .net, oracle-xe

I was wondering if I could get any advice on connecting to Oracle 10g Express to .NET? I saw a solution in one of the threads here, but could not seem to find a download link.

my intention is to use Visual Studio 2010 (.NET 4.0) to connect to a Oracle 10g Express database.

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the files under server/network/admin
You need to setup the TNSNAMES.ora file which would have the credentials for the Express

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = [machinename])(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
```

Listener.ora file
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = [machinename])(PORT = 1521))
    )
 )

And finally check if the listener is up via cmd

```
lsnrctl status
```

This should show you connecting to the XE instance mentioned above.

You will need `Oracle.DataAccess` dll to communicate with the instance, add a reference of it and with the query string you should be good to start off

Comment: Hmm... I was wondering if I can get some advice on where I can download the Oracle.DataAccess.dll file from?

Comment: you can find the same in the bin folder of the Express you have installed

Comment: great .. mark this as answer so that it helps others who are in the same situation